# Just get the image URL from string in PHP

Tags: php, string

From a string such as this `<img src="/images/mylondon.jpg" />` I'm trying to retrieve JUST the url for use elsewhere in PHP

I know Regular expressions are the way to go, but I can't get my head around them right now.

Could anyone be of assistance?

Comment: I've used the answer given below, which works, but is there a better way of doing this? It's not an entire document I'm searching through, just a couple of lines of HTML...

Comment: "Regular expressions are the way to go" Somebody has been deceiving you. Regular expressions are only an acceptable way for regular languages. For the other languages, they can create massive problems. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~<img.*?src=["\']+(.*?)["\']+~', $html, $urls);
$urls = $urls[1]
```

Comment: This regular expression won't work in a lot of situations.  And as always, it's a bad idea to use regular expressions with HTML.

Comment: What would be the best way to grab the `url` from a line of `html` then?

Comment: @shane A more maintainable way would be to use an HTML parser class. For example the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @drrcknlsn: in this case it will work. could you tell me situation when would not regex work on this?

Comment: @genesis It will not match `<img src=foo/>` and other cases.  It will also match things that it should not, like `<img src=''''''''''''>`. @shane You should use a DOM parser.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: `<img src='''''` shouldn't be parsed in any case, because it's not a valid html. My code will give just empty string

Comment: @genesis It will also fail for valid HTML like `<img src=foo alt="bar"/>` because it will match `foo alt="bar`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: tell me one single popular website which is not using quotes

Comment: @genesis It doesn't matter how unpopular it is.  It is valid HTML and sites do use it, unfortunately, which makes this solution unreliable.  It is better to use a DOM parser.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Just a question OT: How does domdocument parse it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3574/discussion-between-genesis--and-drrcknlsn)

Answer (score 2):

> I think it would be better if used DOMDocument object:

```
$text = '<html><body><p>ala bala</p><img src="/images/mylondon.jpg" /></body></html>';
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument;
$htmlDom->loadHTML($text);

$imageTags = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('img');

$extractedImages = array();
foreach($imageTags as $imageTag){
   $extractedImages[] = $imageTag->getAttribute('src');
}

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($extractedImages); exit;
```