# Get image url from content containing an image

Tags: php, html, regex

I am building a small cms system for personal use. A part of it requires me to get the first image url in an article. How can I do this?

**Sample article content in variable `$article`**

```
<p>
<img src="/images/userContent/2013-07-12%2022_27_34.png">
The griefing problem has been curbed!
</p>
```

How can I get the url `/images/userContent/2013-07-12%2022_27_34.png` 

Possibly regex? if yes, how? I am clueless with regex

Comment: possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461922/just-get-the-image-url-from-string-in-php

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse (X)HTML will cause an encounter with [Cthulhu](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: correctly answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @Javier If the OP visited Mike's link, he probably would've found that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class:

```
<?php
    $myhtml = '...'
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($myhtml);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
/images/userContent/2013-07-12%2022_27_34.png
```

**[Working demo!](http://codepad.org/2EnISmZF)**