# Regex: Find only image urls in a string with PHP

Tags: php, regex, image, url

I have a very complex string and i want to find and replace all urls that end with .jpg, .png, or .gif with a static url. For example;

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://www.website.com/images/some.jpg; consul delicata comprehensam eos at. Mea rebum laudem deterruisset et, ex epicuri constituto his. Sea ad appareat democritum. http://www.anotherwebsite.com/images/some.png Omnis vituperata dissentiunt an duo. Sumo diceret lobortis at sed, singulis aliquando prodesset ex sit.";

$regex = ?;
$static_image_url= "http://new_image_url";

return preg_replace($regex, $static_image_url, $string);
```

Please note this string may be more complex than this, urls are dynamic and this is NOT HTML.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best Regards,

EDIT:

This one worked for this case;

```
return preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)/', $static_image_url, $string);
```

Comment: Yeah, so what have you tried?

Comment: I'm middle of nowhere! studied and tried to edit this one but no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461922/just-get-the-image-url-from-string-in-php

Comment: Try something like this to start with: http://regex101.com/r/nX1sN3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should replace the links as long as they don't have a space in them (since links clearly can't have spaces).

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://www.website.com/images/some.jpg; consul delicata comprehensam eos at. Mea rebum laudem deterruisset et, ex epicuri constituto his. Sea ad appareat democritum. http://www.anotherwebsite.com/images/some.png Omnis vituperata dissentiunt an duo. Sumo diceret lobortis at sed, singulis aliquando prodesset ex sit.";
$static_image_url= "http://new_image_url";
return preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)/', $static_image_url, $string);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've found a very smilar one that worked. But yours seems much detailed.

Comment: The problem with yours is that it does not do what it should.  For example, it replaces `htt://test.jpg` and `http://www.the link.jpg` and you're welcome.

Comment: Yes, yours definitely better!

Comment: Thanks.  Good luck with your program.  Also, if you want to **allow** spaces in links, you can just replace the `[^ ]` with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

For figuring out a regex, use the online tools for testing out your string.

http://www.regextester.com.

Since in your example string all your links start with "http://" we can start our pattern with that.  We know that they are going to end in the extension of the file type (jpg, png) and a whole mess of stuff in between.

```
http:\/\/.+?(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)
```

Using `.+` will match anything and appending `?` makes it ungreedy.  Otherwise, we will get everything from the beginning of the first link to the end of the last.

**Warning**  This regex is based on your example string.  If the links are 'www.someplace.com/someimage.jpg'  it won't be matched

Comment: This would incorrectly replace links such as `http://www.website.com/images/somejpg`.  Also, you forgot `.gif`.